# is it possible to show a clueTip tooltip when i change a select dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, tooltip, cluetip

i am doing a review of [clueTip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/).  i see this can be used when you hover over some div or when you click on a link but i wanted to see if you can "trigger" showing a tooltip when you click on a certain item in a select dropdown.  Does anyone know if this is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the FAQ section for it:
http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/#faq

So there I see:

> New as of clueTip 1.0.3: How do I
>   programmatically close (hide) a
>   clueTip?
>       If you want to trigger a clueTip to close, based on some other
>   interaction, you can use the following
>   code:
>   $(document).trigger('hideCluetip');

So I believe you can use this and listen for 'change' event for combobox and show/hide tip.